# How to clear spaces in association analysis

Tags: r, web-scraping, associations, text-mining, arules

Text mining association analysis

How to clear spaces

To see the result of association rule creation,

There are blank characters (lhs).(For example this appears)

```
[1]  {}       => {monday}   0.012672811 0.012672811 1.000000

[2]  {}       => {happy}   0.007488479 0.007488479 1.000000

[3]  {}       => {money}   0.007488479 0.007488479 1.000000
```

It should be removed when you use "arulesViz graph".

There are a lot of unnamed circles because of spaces.

What should I do?
Thank you for your advice.

```
library(KoNLP) 
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)

text1<-readLines(file.choose())
text1
Encoding(text1)<- "UTF-8"


text1 <- readLines(text1)
lword <- Map(extractNoun,text1) 
lword <- unique(lword)
lword <- sapply(lword, unique) 
filter1 <- function(x){
  nchar(x) <= 4 && nchar(x) >= 2 && is.hangul(x)
}
filter2 <- function(x){
  Filter(filter1, x)
}
lword <- sapply(lword, filter2)
install.packages("arules")
library(arules) 
wordtran <- as(lword, "transactions")
wordtable <- crossTable(wordtran)
tranrules <- apriori(wordtran, parameter=list(supp=0.01, conf=0.05)) 
inspect(tranrules)
rules <- labels(tranrules, ruleSep=" ")
rules <- sapply(rules, strsplit, " ",  USE.NAMES=F) 
rulemat <- do.call("rbind", rules)
#---------------------------------------------     
#▽Association analysis visualization
#---------------------------------------------  
install.packages("arulesViz")
library(arulesViz)
plot(tranrules, method="graph", control=list(type="items"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is copied from the manual page of `apriori` in `arules`:

**Note:** Apriori only creates rules with one item in the RHS (Consequent)! The default value in APparameter for minlen is 1. This means that rules with only one item (i.e., an empty antecedent/LHS) like

```
{} => {beer}
```

will be created. These rules mean that no matter what other items are involved, the item in the RHS will appear with the probability given by the rule's confidence (which equals the support). If you want to avoid these rules then use the argument `parameter=list(minlen=2)`.